# Angular 2 Input validation with value binding

Tags: angular

I have in my project a form with an input like this:

```
@Input()
article: Article;
ngOnInit() {
this.articleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: [ '', Validators.required]
});
```

form.component.html:

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="title"
           type="text" value="{{article ? article.title : ''}}" />
```

Article is an Object with title attribute and article is an input property.

The Problem is when the input property get an article with a valid title **the input value change to the value of the title but strangely steal in invalid state !**

Can any one give me an idea of what happening please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing, 'value="{{article ? article.title : ''}}"' can be simplified to 'value="{{article?.title}}"'

Comment: I like to ensure the readability, thank you any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the reactive form doesn't register the value of `value`. If you use one-way-binding your form control will register it:

```
<input formControlName="title" [ngModel]="article?.title" />
```

Notice the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) here, so that it will not throw error if there is no value.